# Is the distribution of sample mean of Bernoulli random variable a Binomial distribution?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution, central-limit-theorem, bernoulli-distribution

As written in the title, is the distribution of sample mean of Bernoulli random variable a Binomial distribution? And I was taught that we can approximate Binomial distribution to normal distribution due to CLT. Is the title the reason we can approximate it?

I think, if $X \sim Bern(p)$, and say $X_n$ is the sum of the elements of the sample of scale $n$, i.e. $X_n=n\bar{X_n}$ then $$Pr(X_n=k)={n \choose k}p^kq^{n-k}$$so $X_n \sim Bin(n,p)$.

And due to CLT, which ststes $$\sqrt{n}( \bar{X_n} -\mu)\overset {d}{\to} N(0,\sigma^2),$$
the distribution of sample mean $\bar{X_n}$ tents to follow $N(\mu,\frac{\sigma^2}{n})$ as $n$ gets bigger, and therefore $X_n=n\bar{X_n}$ tends to follow $N(n\mu, n\sigma^2)$.

And if we apply this consequence to random variable $X \sim Bern(p), $ then since $E(X)=p$ and $V(x)=pq$,
$X_n \sim Bin(n,p)$ tends to follow $N(n\mu  ,n \sigma^2 )=N(np, npq).$

Is this the right way to suggest we can approximate binomial distribution to normal distribution by CLT? Or is it wrong and does there exist other way to suggest it?

#Since I'm new to statistic and I'm Korean, I would appreciate if you forgive some improper expressions.

Comment: I think you should write $P(X_n = k) = \binom{n}{k}p^kq^{\color{red}{n-k}}$.

Comment: @Riemann Oh that was right. I will edit

Answer (score 0):

No, as you said, sum of n **independent** bernulli random variables is binomial but if $Y\sim Bin(n,p)$ then $aY$ is not binomial (a≠1).
You can compare the support of $aY$ to binomial to see why $aY$ is not binomial. The support of binomial is like $\{0,1,...,n\}$ but support of $aY$ is $\{0,a,2a,...,an\}$ which is different. Also there are other ways to show that $aY$ is not binomial but if you plot the probability distributions of $aY$ and $Y$, you see that they are similar but it doesn't mean that $aY$ is binomial.

Also, take a look at this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/507677/linear-transformation-of-a-binomial-random-variable).